# Combining MVC and JS Identity Server authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, identity, identityserver3

I have a MVC web application that uses [Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) to manage authentication. This works fine, redirecting the browser to the identity server to login, then redirecting back to my application.

However, since my application uses a fair amount of Ajax and javascript calls, I have an issue where the page will attempt to redirect when one of the Ajax methods is called and does not redirect back to the application correctly.

Looking at the documentation, it appears that the [JS Authentication](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/jsGettingStarted.html) will give me what I want, allowing me to silently refresh the authentication token either with a popup or an iFrame.

I have set up my application as per the documentation, using [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) but I cannot get my application to silently reload the token, and my Ajax calls still fail.

My oidc-client setup code runs on page load and looks like:

```
var settings = {
    authority: 'http://localhost:8000/identity',
    client_id: 'client',
    popup_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8000/popup.html',
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8000/silentrenew.html',

    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid profile email api',
    filter_protocol_claims: true
};

var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(settings);
```

The client is set up with the Hybrid flow and setup to allow redirects from the popup.html and silentrenew.html files.

Popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="/js/oidc-client.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Oidc.Log.logger = console;
        Oidc.Log.logLevel = Oidc.Log.INFO;
        new Oidc.UserManager().signinPopupCallback();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Silentrenew.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/js/oidc-client.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Oidc.Log.logger = console;
        Oidc.Log.logLevel = Oidc.Log.INFO;
        new Oidc.UserManager().signinSilentCallback();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone assist in why my authentication token is not renewing using the silent redirect uri, or how I can solve my problem of renewing a token on an Ajax call.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in the end? I'm in a similar position...ultimately i would like my javascript client to automatically be logged in at the same time as my mvc app.

Comment: @PaulHinett no, I ended up setting the RedirectUri of my client to the main page of my application so I at least didn't end up on a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet loads the client UserManager but it doesn't attempt to load the user. You'll likely see log entries confirming that.

So now you need logic to determine how to log in the user after the line

`var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(settings);`

In my application I have already authenticated the user to the OP so a idsrv and idsrv.session cookie already exist. In my case I can call `mgr.signinSilent();` and that will step up and restore the sessionStorage for the user as well as kick off the autorenew logic (my code for silentRenew.html is identical).

If you don't have a session then you could use either `mgr.signinRedirect()` or `mgr.signinPopup()` depending on what suits your application. These methods and a few more details are available [on the github wiki](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki)